# segfault when trying to access a string member of a class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdstring

I have a class `Message` that has a `std::string` as a data member, defined like this:

```
class Message
{
// Member Variables
    private:
        std::string text;
        (...)

// Member Functions
    public:
        Message(const std::string& t)
        : text(t) {}

        std::string getText() const {return text;}
        (...)
};
```

This class is used in a vector in another class, like this:

```
class Console
{
// Member Variables
    private:
        std::vector<Message> messageLog;
        (...)

// Member Functions
    public:
        Console()
        {
            messageLog.push_back(Message("Hello World!"));
        }

        void draw() const;
};
```

In `draw()`, there's an iterator that calls `getText()`.  When it does, the program segfaults.  I've determined that `text` is valid inside the `Message` constructor.  However, I can't tell if it's valid from inside `Console`.  I'm assuming it is, but if I try to inspect indices of `Console`'s messageLog, gdb tells me this:

`(gdb) p messageLog[0]

 One of the arguments you tried to pass to operator[] could not be converted to what 
 the function wants.`

Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT:  here's `draw()`.  `TCODConsole` is part of a curses library I'm using, and so this function prints each message in `Console` to a part of the curses screen.  `TL` and `BR` are `Point` member objects (two ints) that tell where on the screen to draw `Console`.  I left out parts of `Message` and `Console` in the original question to hopefully make things clearer, but if you need me to post the entire classes then I can.  They aren't too long.

```
void Console::draw() const
        {
            int x = TL.getX(), y = TL.getY();
            int width = BR.getX() - TL.getX();
            int height = BR.getY() - TL.getY();

            // draw the Console frame
            TCODConsole::root->printFrame(x, y, width, height, true);

            // print the Console's messages
            vector<Message>::const_iterator it;
            for(it=messageLog.begin(); it<messageLog.begin()+height-1; ++it)
            {
                string message = "%c" + it->getText();
                TCODConsole::setColorControl(TCOD_COLCTRL_1, 
                                             it->getForeColor(),
                                             it->getBackColor());
                y += TCODConsole::root->printRectEx(x, y, width, height,
                                                    TCOD_BKGND_NONE,
                                                    TCOD_LEFT,
                                                    message.c_str(),
                                                    TCOD_COLCTRL_1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"In `draw()`, there's an iterator that calls `getText()`"* - how does that look like?

Comment: Yep, show the `draw()` source.

Comment: Stop using `<pre><code>` tags to format code. SO does not display such code correctly (the angle brackets in particular). Use the formatting buttons instead.

Comment: I never noticed those before.  Thanks for pointing that out; I won't use <pre><code> again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that by the point you use `it->getText()`, the iterator is NULL. Add a check `it != messageLog.end()` when you walk the array, and before calling `it->getText()`.

Comment: This was the problem.  I was so focused on thinking about a `Console` with 500+ elements, I didn't think about it with only one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it definitely `std::vector messageLog` and not `std::vector<Message> messageLog`?  That seems a bit odd.

Comment: That was a typo.  It is `std::vector<Message> messageLog`.

Comment: it dropped the `<Message>` part of the line because SO apparently thought it was a tag.  Is there a way to stop it from doing that within <pre><code> tags?

Comment: @Max: Stop using `<pre><code>` tags to format code. SO does not display such code correctly (the angle brackets in particular). Use the formatting buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

What does the height have to do with the vector's index? You have:

```
messageLog.begin()+height-1;
```

Why are you adding the screen coordinate to the iterator? That seems to be your problem and you're most likely overindexing and that's why you're getting a SIGSEGV.

What you probably want is to simply iterate over all the messages in the vector and display them at a particular location on the screen. I see what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to calculate the screen boundary using the iterator you're definitely going about it the wrong way. Try running a counter or get `messageLog.size()` and then recalculate the height with each iteration. As for the loop just do:

```
for(it=messageLog.begin(); it!=messageLog.end(); ++it)
```

Answer (score -2):

It's probably because the scope of the `Message` object created in the `Console` method is just the `Console` method. So, if your program is trying to access this object in another method, like `draw`, you will get this segmentation fault, since this object is deleted after the execution.

Try this (just insert a `new` keyword):

```
    Console()
    {
        messageLog.push_back(new Message("Hello World!"));
    }
```

In this case, the object is not deleted after Console's end.

Just remember to delete the objects created when your program doesn't need them anymore.

Comment: `push_back` will construct a copy of its argument, which has lifetime until the `std::vector` is destroyed or the element is removed or overwritten.